# How to check that a class has a method before calling it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there anyway of checking that a class has a method before calling it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In more general case for a **class** `myClass` which inherits `NSObject`:

`if ([myClass instancesRespondToSelector: @selector(mySelector)])`

For an **object** `myObject` which inherits `NSObject`:

`if ([myObject respondsToSelector: @selector(mySelector)])`

Comment: @middaparka thanks, however the first idea was something like `[[[myClass alloc] autorelease] respondsToSelector: @selector(mySelector)]` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the "respondsToSelector" method within each class as follows;

```
if([targetObject respondsToSelector:@selector(myOptionalMethod)]) {
    [targetObject myOptionalMethod];
}
```

Comment: for a class you can't use respondsToSelector

Comment: @Martin Babacaev I meant object (have tweaked), if you're referring to the fact that you can't use respondsToSelector on class that hasn't been instantiated. :-)

Comment: @Martin Babacaev Thanks for the nudge though. (My mistake.) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some code like this:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:)]) {
```